# How to add another key combination for copy and paste in macOS Catalina

Tags: hotkeys, macos-catalina

I would like to add another key combination for the copy and paste operations.

- Copy will be  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  <kbd>C</kbd> and  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>M</kbd>.
- Paste will be  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  <kbd>V</kbd> and  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want to do that.

Even if you could - there's no inbuilt facility to add two commands to one function -  overriding basic system-wide commands is hard if not impossible, you would be in conflict with system-wide 'new document' & 'minimise'.

Comment: So how lefties do copy paste?
Since the left hand is on the trackpad, it's impossible to reach to CMD+C & CMD+V

Comment: I presume - as they've been a long-suffering invisible minority for so many years - they just have to deal with it, the same as right-handed scissors…